# Authentication and Authorization on a simple restful webservice

Tags: java, authorization, restful-authentication

I developed a basic Restful Webservice in eclipse by using maven. I use tomcat 7.0 as a server, the SE 1.7 and jersey as my JAX-RS source, but I don't use JPA. I have a MySql DB  and i connect to the DB with Connector J provided by MySql. I have a employee table and a deparment table in my DB and the suitable model classes for those tables. My webservice only provides get-methods that return the employees and deparmentinformation in the JSON format.

It works perfectly fine, but now I want the client to log in before gaining access to the webservice-methods.

The client is not set jet, but it should be a website, on my tomcat server that uses javascript and JQuery to interact with the webservice.

Now I want to add a authentication and authorization service to my webservice. This should check if the user is logged-in and has the permissions to ask for a defined employee or department. For example one of my get-methods is:

```
@GET
@Path("/employee/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return EmployeeDBService.getDefinedEmployee(id);
}
```

and now it is called by the client with serverurl/myresource/employee/10
but the user logged in the client does not have the permission to ask for employee with the id 10.

I also want to add a feature that logs out the client after beeing a while inactive.

I have already searched for a good tutorial and technology to implement the authentication and authorization service to the webservice. But I wasn't really successful, because:

- I am new to developing Java restful webservices.
- And I found only examples that are implemented in a SOAP webservice and never read something about a automatical log-out after some time beeing inactive.

Does someone of you know good links / examples / technologies how to solve my problem?

If there a any question I will answer them. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. I would stick to asking how to achieve what you need to achieve and not ask for links/tools/code. And be aware that this is not an easy topic, if you look for easy answers - there are none. Security is of course a standard part of the technology stack, Since it is Jersey, it has a nice user manual with a nice chapter on security. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html . But that chapter does assume you know the ins and outs of JavaEE security. (edit: sorry, you did mention Jersey)

Comment: " And be aware that this is not an easy topic, if you look for easy answers - there are none. Security is of course a standard part of the technology stack" Exactly this is my problem. I am learning how to develop a restful webservice since a few days, but i found no source that combine the knowledge I really need to solve the given problem. This all is part of a project I have to hand in in about 2 months, and I do not want to do everything in the last week........ But my search for a really good source still wasn't successful. I only learned Java one year ago...... But thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the [security chapter in the Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html) will show you how to integrate the authentication mechanism in your REST APIs: This part of the authentication will only check if the user is logged and who he is.

> the user logged in the client does not have the permission to ask for employee with the id 10

JAX/RS does not know anything about your data model and their privileges. But he will give you its login. You must implement the logic on your own. Probably this will be the first line of each of your REST methods.

Comment: That means, e.g. that I connect to my DB where I saved the usernames, passwords and their persmissions and check befor retruning something whether the logged user, I know, has the permission to that call?

Comment: Exactly. Or: The SecurityContext can also give you which are the roles of the user (SecurityContext.isUserInRole). If the number of employee is low, you may use a role for each employee.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help Emmanuel Keller, I think this should help me.

Comment: Look into XACML or Apache Shiro or Spring security for the authorization (access control) piece